# How to Show and Hide Div using C# in MVC 2 aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie in doing MVC and got stucked in middle someone guide me.

I want to hide `div` in view based on controller action.

**View code:**

```
<div id="mudetails" runat="server" style="width: 99%; padding-top: 4%">
</div>
```

this is my parent div inside content is present.

**Controller code.**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {  
            // div "mudetails" should not apper
            return View();
        }

 public ActionResult Index(string textbox)
        {
               // div "mudetails" should apper

        }
```

In pageload the `div` should not apper but when `ActionResult Index(string textbox)` action is triggerd the `div` should appear.. I tried but not able to find correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return something in your model to indicate whether or not it should display. At its simplest:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {  
        // div "mudetails" should not apper
        return View(false);
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string textbox)
    {
       // div "mudetails" should apper
       return View(true);
    }
```

and then in your view:

```
    @Model bool

    @if (model) {
        <div id="mudetails" runat="server" style="width: 99%; padding-top: 4%">
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult Index()
  {  
        // div "mudetails" should not apper
        mudetails.Visible = false;
        return View();
    }

public ActionResult Index(string textbox)
    {
           // div "mudetails" should apper
              mudetails.Visible = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put something like this in your controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {  
        ViewBox.ShowDetails = false;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string textbox)
    {
           ViewBox.ShowDetails = true;

    }
```

Then in your view you can use the following

```
@if (ViewBox.ShowDetails) {
    <div id="mudetails" runat="server" style="width: 99%; padding-top: 4%">
    </div>
}
```