# Alternative for asp:panel in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Now that every thing is being converted from the conventional aspx to razor view because of its benefits,
my question is how to achieve thing similar to panel, where in we were allowed that if X is true, show the panel else visible = false.

How can we achieve a similar thing in MVC?

Comment: Just use a `@if(X) { // render the html }`

Comment: So what is `panel` once rendered? nothing but a `div`. My first search attempt would be "how to show/hide div in mvc". I did so and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595165/how-to-show-and-hide-div-using-c-sharp-in-mvc-2-aspx

Comment: @StephenMuecke  
if we are using if else just to show particular div's, then what is the difference between aspx and razor, because razor was meant to be free from the code behind ?

Comment: It would be shorter to answer _what is the same_ :) Not sure what you mean by _razor was meant to be free from the code behind_ (there is no such thing as _code behind_ in MVC)

Comment: I know there is no code behind in MVC, but if the view is tightly coupled in this approach (by the controller/or model value) , I am thinking your first line is true. The both are almost the same. :/

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with razor in the view:

```
@if(condition) {
    <div>............ </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The panel is actually `<div id="yourdivid">...</div>` element in MVC view, thus you can either process condition directly on view as Matteo1010 said, or use JS if you want to setup views with only passed values and HTML helpers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var condition = '@[passed condition value here]';

if (condition) {
     // show panel
     document.getElementById("yourdivid").style.visibility = "visible";
}
else {
     // hide panel
     document.getElementById("yourdivid").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
<div id="yourdivid"></div>
```

I think JS approach with passed value has more advantage to control the view behaviour in client-side than write C# code directly inside the view.